# How to decode IMAP body content

Tags: php, dom, xpath, fetch, imap

I want to decode email I receive in the inbox so I wrote:

```
$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1));
dd($message);

                        $doc = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
                        $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                        $doc->loadHTML($message);
                        $doc->saveHTML();
                        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
```

but `$message` is coded string like:

```
"""
IApRdWFuZG9vIdgsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsgBhcnRuZXIuCkNsaWNrIGhlcmUg\r\n
aWYgdGhpcyBlbWFpbfhjfghfhfghfghfghcmx5LgpRdWFuZG9vCkxvZ2luOiBM\r\n
b25kb24gU3RlYWtob3VzZSBDby4gLSBDaGVsc2VhCiANCllvdSBoYXZlIGEgbmV3IHJlc2VydmF0\r\n
aW9uLg0KWW91IGhhdmUgYSBuZXcgY29uZmlybWVkIHJlc2VydmF0aW9uIGZyb20gUXVhbmRvbyAo\r\n
... ... ... etc.
```

How I can decode this string and create DOM I can use ?
Any idea?

Comment: I wrote this a wile ago mainly for GMAIL, it's not complete but it may give you some ideas [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/IMAP)  IN particular is this file [Results](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/IMAP/Result.php) which contains stuff for decoding emails.

Comment: 1. That's base64, not quoted-printable. 2. Get whoever is sending you email to set the correct `Content-Encoding:` headers in their emails and PHP's IMAP library should decode it properly for you.

Comment: I tried                 $message = imap_base64(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1));
 but I don't get HTML code just text like: "Click here if this email does not display properly.\n
HotelNews\n
Login: London - Chelsea\n